# Group/merge array values based on a set number range

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, slice, reduce

Js newbie here.

I have the following array:

```js
Array [
  Array [
    "Canadian",
    "57",
  ],
  Array [
    "",
    "Tire",
    "64",
  ],
  Array [
    "",
    "#",
    "67",
  ],
  Array [
    "",
    "168",
    "68",
  ],
  Array [
    "",
    "65",
    "84",
  ],
  Array [
    "",
    "Pinebush",
    "84",
  ],
  Array [
    "",
    "Road",
    "86",
  ],
  Array [
    "",
    ",",
    "87",
  ],
  Array [
    "",
    "Cambridge",
    "88",
  ],
  Array [
    "",
    "ON",
    "90",
  ],
  Array [
    "",
    "Bruno",
    "108",
  ],
  Array [
    "",
    "R",
    "109",
  ],
  Array [
    "",
    ",",
    "109",
  ],
  Array [
    "",
    "General",
    "109",
  ],
  Array [
    "",
    "Manager",
    "110",
  ],
]
```

which I would like to turn into following array:

```js
Array [
  Array [
    "Canadian Tire # 168",
    "57 64 67 68",
  ],
  Array [
    "65 Pinebush Road , Cambridge ON",
    "84 86 87 88 90",
  ],
  Array [
    "Bruno R , General Manager",
    "108 109 109 109 110",
  ],
]
```

The values in nested arrays change from strings to numbers, punctuation marks and whitespace.
But the last values in arrays are  y-coordinates for each word position, ie:

```
"Canadian", <---word
"57", <----its y-coordinate


"",<--- empty string
"Tire",<---another word
"64",<---another y-coordiante
```

The goal is to group words according to their y-coordinates falling within a small range difference:

57 64 67 68 are all within difference of 11,

84 86 87 88 90 are all within difference of 6 or

108 109 109 109 110 are all within difference of 2.

How would one accomplish this in vanilla js?

much obliged!

Comment: Is this a typo:  `Array [  "Canadian", "57", ]`? You have here any `""`as fisrt element like in the other arrays.

Comment: I would advice you to try to solve it on your own first. Even if you don't know JS very well you can write pseudo-code.

Comment: @Saschano no, the first one doesn't have any empty quotes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about this:

```js
var originalArray=[["Canadian","57"],["","Tire","64"],["","#","67"],["","168","68"],["","65","84"],["","Pinebush","84"],["","Road","86"],["",",","87"],["","Cambridge","88"],["","ON","90"],["","Bruno","108"],["","R","109"],["",",","109"],["","General","109"],["","Manager","110"]];

var newArray=[];

for(var item of originalArray) {
  var age=Number(item[item.length-1]);
  var group=age<80?0:age<100?1:2;
  if(newArray[group]==undefined) newArray[group]=[[],[]];
  for(var j=0; j<item.length-1; j++) if(item[j]!="") newArray[group][0].push(item[j]);
  newArray[group][1].push(item[item.length-1]);
}

for(var item of newArray) {
  item[0]=item[0].join(" ");
  item[1]=item[1].join(" ");
}

for(var item of newArray) console.log(item);
```

It's assuming last sub-item is the age you want to group by.
I've manually grouped by under 80, then by under 100, and then - by the rest.  You can modify that (you didn't specify how to find groups...).
It's adding the values into sub-arrays, and joining to a string afterwards.

Comment: thank you, this works well. But to answer your question, I do not know how exactly to know groups ie you've picked 80 and 100 but the array values will change dynamically and I am unable to manually group by specific age. I was thinking about looking at sub-values (ages) and grouping those that are within a 12 point difference without knowing actual values, if this makes sense.

Comment: You need to come up with a way to split by ages - either by some age, or into 3 groups, or - I don't know...   It depends on what you need...

Comment: I just realized: are those ages or something else?!?

Comment: its actually y-coordiante of a corresponding word.

Comment: that's the problem, there is no set number of groups or certain number.

Comment: I don't know what "y-coordiante of a corresponding word" means...

Comment: little backstory, all these words are fetched from google vision api OCR. The numbers are one of the y-coordinates of a bounding box around these words. By collecting words with similar bounding boxes I am able to split words into complete sentences on separate lines..)

Comment: Well, 110-57 is 53.  Divided by 3 is about 18.  That splits the values into what you wrote:  [57, 64, 67, 68], [84, 86, 87, 88, 90], [108, 109, 109, 109, 110]...

Comment: something like this: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/images/para_out.jpg

Comment: Aha!!!  Interesting!!!
Can you get the height of the text?
And/Or the x-coordinate?

Comment: yes, I do have x,y coordinates of words and x,y coordinates of each letter in that word
(bounding box around each will have four sets of coordinates for top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right)

Comment: so hence i only took the bottom right y-coordinate of each word and then by comparing the difference I should be able to tell if the words are on the same line.

Comment: I think you should use all the 4 corners to find "rows" and "columns".
This way you can compare boxes and see if they are closer to being on the same row vs column...